# HighCharts node-export-server y-axis labels missing

Tags: highcharts

We have setup our own HighCharts node-export-server as shown in the official documentation. We are able to get images back from the server, however when requesting a column chart the y-axis labels are missing. If we submit the same chart data to https://export.highcharts.com/ we get the correct image.

Here is the chart data as submitted (to both servers):

```
    {
    'chart': { 
        'type': 'column',
        'width': 800,
        'height': 500
    },
    'title': { 'text': '' },
    'xAxis': { 'categories': ['Damage Code'], 'crosshair': true },
    'yAxis': { 
        'min': 0, 
        'title': { 'text': 'Tire Life (Hours)' }, 
        'plotLines': [{ 
            'value': 800, 
            'color': '#929292', 
            'dashStyle': 'shortdash', 
            'width': 2
        } ]
    },
    'colors': ['#ff0000', '#000000', '#787878', '#5eb749', '#2893d1', '#5ec7bd', '#f79226', '#ff7043', '#ee3124', '#a9a9a9', '#333333'],
    'tooltip': { 'enabled': false },
    'plotOptions': { 
        'series': { 
            'dataLabels': { 
                'align': 'center', 
                'color': '#282E32', 
                'enabled': true, 
                'format': '{point.label}'
            } 
        }, 
        'column': { 
            'pointPadding': 0.2, 
            'borderWidth': 0 
        } 
    },
    'series': [{"name":"(111) Test Code Description 1","showInLegend":true,"data":[{"y":1000,"label":"111 10%"}]},{"name":"(222) Test Code Description 2","showInLegend":true,"data":[{"y":2000,"label":"222 20%"}]},{"name":"(1212) Test Code Description 12","showInLegend":true,"data":[{"y":1200,"label":"1212 120%"}]}]
}
```

And the image returned from the node-server:
[image: Chart Rendered on our node-server]

I've checked out the GitHub (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server ) page and not much has happened there since we setup the node-server so there is nothing new to deploy from there.

**Updated**: Getting back to this I see the repository has some changes since I last checked. I've grabbed the latest code in the repository and re-published to my chart server. The issue continues, but I've got some additional information now.

If I set the yAxis rotation to 0 (zero) it shows. Any other rotation (270 is the default) results in the title showing as 'dots' as shown in the image above.

So this will show the title:

```
'yAxis': { 
    'min': 0, 
    'title': { 'text': 'Tire Life (Hours)', rotation: 0 },
```

This will not:

```
    'yAxis': { 
    'min': 0, 
    'title': { 'text': 'Tire Life (Hours)', rotation: 270 },
```

I don't consider rotation zero a solution, but hopefully this helps to identify the issue.

Comment: I've tested it on both local export server and export.highcharts.com. The result is the same and correct in both places. Could you share the code of your export server?

Comment: We just used the code on the GitHub page (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server ) with no modification. Is there a specific part to look at, i.e. chart.js, server.js? I wouldn't think the index.js, logger.js, or phantompool.js would contribute to this.

Comment: Ok, could you describe how you've installed 'node-export-server'? What modules have you chosen? What version on highcharts and export-server you have?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel - I downloaded the repository and copied it to a new Node.js project in Visual Studio. I also ran npm install and answered the appropriate question that were presented (i.e. version number, map options, etc.). I then published the app to an Azure Web App, running Windows w/ASP.Net v4.7 as the runtime stack. Finally I told the Azure app to use Node v10 minimum. I've setup a test environment here: https://eps-highchartsexport.azurewebsites.net/ For testing I"m hitting it w/Postman and the payload {type: image/png, options: above JSON}